# Excel data format problem datetime with apostrophe?

Tags: excel, phpexcel

We use to upload excel file to our head office software, what their requirement is that apostrophe must be there in start of datetime such as "   '2020-05-02 12:31:54.000  " but it should not visible in cell but only in formula bar. As shown in first Q1 selected cell below:
[image]

My programming script fetch data with apostrophe, then I manually select cell one by one and press F2 then enter which fulfill my requirement but the problem is it takes alot of time. Is there any shortcut for this, I tried formating, Data and someformula but nothing work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by just replacing apostrophe with an apostrophe. :)